# Why does my Oxygen25 work with Logic, but not Pro Tools?

Tags: midi, logic-pro, pro-tools

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [My Oxygen25 midi keyboard wont work with Pro Tools 9, help..?](https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/2452/my-oxygen25-midi-keyboard-wont-work-with-pro-tools-9-help)

So, I have an Oxygen25 midi keyboard. When I use it with Logic, things work fine; but when I try to use it with Pro Tools I get this:

[image: Pro Tools Error]

I've tried to restart Pro Tools, and unplug and replug all my hardware.. But nothing seems to fix it. Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: This question is addressed [here](http://avp.stackexchange.com/questions/2452/my-oxygen25-midi-keyboard-wont-work-with-pro-tools-9-help/2544#2544)